# Typedefs with tweaked alignment

Tags: c++, gcc, types

The 'Type Attributes' [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) for gcc, gives a very interesting example of how to tweak the alignment on type aliases:

```
typedef int more_aligned_int __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In this example, `more_aligned_int` has different alignment that `int`, which becomes apparent when declaring an array of those guys:

```
aligned_int ar[3];
```

outputs

```
error: alignment of array elements is greater than element size
       aligned_int ar[3];
                       ^
```

The standard C++ alternative, would be `alignas`, and while I was amazed to find out that you can actually write:

```
using aligned_int = int alignas(8);
```

compiling the above gives:

```
warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
         using aligned_int = int alignas(8);
note: an attribute that appertains to a type-specifier is ignored
```

so there is no side effect, and that's why the aforementioned array declaration succeeds. Question time:

- So `alignas` isn't equivalent to the `aligned` attribute?
- Are there more ways they differ?
- Is there a standard way, for creating such typedefs (alignment tweaks) for built-in types?

Comment: alignas does not apply to `int`

Comment: @spectras Yes, I know. That's not the question

Comment: Well it kind of does: the standard way does not apply to `int`. You have to wrap it in a class to get that result. As for ways they differ, they don't apply to the same types: the attribute is universal while alignas is not.

Comment: @LorahAttkins You asked for the differences; that's a biggie. How is it not the question

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Said as a 'one liner' the comment seemed dismissive of the question. Also I've already stated that 'an attribute that appertains to a type-specifier is ignored' . In light of the second comment, I can see how it fits to a bigger picture

Answer (score 3):

These are not the same thing. One is a GCC extension, and the other is a standard language feature.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas):

> The alignas specifier may be applied to the declaration of a variable or a non-bitfield class data member, or it can be applied to the declaration or definition of a class/struct/union or enumeration. It cannot be applied to a function parameter or to the exception parameter of a catch clause.

So the standard feature doesn't apply to `int`.

The extension does (but then you fall foul of the consequences such that the array cannot exist).

Enumerating all the differences between the two unrelated features is probably not useful.

> Is there a standard way, for creating such typedefs (alignment tweaks) for built-in types?

You can wrap your built-in type in a `struct`:

```
struct alignas(8) aligned_int
{
    int val;
};

aligned_int ar[3];
```

But notice that [this compiles](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecff6253c66860b1) (presumably because the size of `aligned_int` has changed accordingly).